# Getting undefined values from my .json file/ First time js node user

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, unit-testing, testing

I'm not to JS node and am having a problem with using my test fixture (a .json file). Here is my .json file:

```
{
"info": [
    {
        "type": "person",
        "gender": "Male",
        "altUrl": "http://www.testUrl.com",
        "contact": {
            "email": {
                "type": "Work",
                "address": "testEmail@email.com",
            },
            "phone": {
                "type": "Mobile",
                "number": "8989898989"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

And in my .js file I have:
`var account = require('../../myfile.json');`

The problem is, when I try to access the data from my .json file, it always comes back as undefined. An example of me calling the .json file is: `console.log(account.info.gender);`

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I'm getting undefined values? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: `account.info[0].gender`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

`info` is an array that's why you have to access like in below example

```
account.info[0].gender
```

Answer (score 0):

`info` is an array, not an object. The `.` is only for accessing object properties. To access the first element of the array you need to use `account.info[0].gender`.

Info as an object:

```
{
    "info": {
        "type": "person",
        "gender": "Male",
        "altUrl": "http://www.testUrl.com",
        "contact": {
            "email": {
                "type": "Work",
                "address": "testEmail@email.com",
            },
            "phone": {
                "type": "Mobile",
                "number": "8989898989"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Now since an array is unnecessary at this point, how would I go about changing this to an object?